# How to switch to child windows covered but other windows in gnome 3?

Tags: gnome, gnome3

In gnome 3, some applications open windows that are not reachable via overview mode or task switching shortcuts. For example, when Eclipse starts, if the workspace dialog got covered by another window, the only way to reach it is to hide all other windows using `Super+H` until it visible.

There should be 3 different window switching shortcuts with different advertised functionality:

- Switch application: `Super+Tab`
- Switch windows: `Alt+Tab`
- Switch windows of an application: `` Alt+` ``

All these perform exactly the same; switch between main application windows!!

It is common that an application appears to be halted but it actually opened a window waiting for user input but this window lost the focus, got covered by other windows and is not reachable via the overview or keyboard!

Comment: Can you see the hidden window when you right click the application icon in the gnome overview dock? Normally you see a list of open windows an application has over there

Comment: No. It only lists windows reachable via task switching keys. Also, Eclipse does not list any window at all in the overview if the main window is not opened yet (That is before selecting the workspace) despite that the splash window and workspace dialog are displayed.